# Process.Start() throws "Could not determine which .NET to use!"

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-xp, c#-2.0

I have a program that launches a second program. It works great on Windows 7 / Vista, executing the UAC as wanted and booting the app. However, when running on XP when it gets to booting the app it returns this error:

> ".NET Framework Initialization Error
>
> Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application."

I tried on two computers, both throw the same error. They both have 4.0 framework, and booting the second app directly works fine without a problem, so there is a problem with Process.Start or ProcessStartInfo. Here is my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo launcher = new ProcessStartInfo();
launcher.Verb = "runas";
launcher.FileName = launcherPath;
Process.Start(launcher);
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Does your launched program require a specific Framework version? Is that version installed?

Comment: I've set it in VS to target 2.0 in order to hit the largest audience.

Comment: It looks like the target application to be launched with Process.Start needs a .NET version that is missing in XP and present in Win 7, maybe .NET 3 or 3.5, which is a part of 7 but not XP, or requires .NET 1.1. Try to install all the versions, 1.1, 3.5 (v2 included), 4.

Comment: I have checked in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework and all from 1.0 to 4.0.30319, including 2.0.50727 (which my program targets) are present.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to but something like this in your config file:

```
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version = "v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Change version  as required.

Does this do it on all machines running XP or have you just tried on the one machine? If you have only tried on one machine running XP, try it on another to verify. If only failing on the one machine you just might need to cleanup the .Net environment on that machine.

http://www.4shared.com/zip/eSJ9ymvf/dotnetfx_cleanup_tool.html

Comment: Damn, darn site strip out my code example. Edited to add it back

Comment: Visual Studio adds that XML tag automatically.

Comment: Did you verify the runtime in the config is installed on the XP machine?

Comment: Yes: "I have checked in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework and all from 1.0 to 4.0.30319, including 2.0.50727 (which my program targets) are present"